Setup an AD Domain in Hyper-V with external switch
I have 3 VMs in my Hyper-V. One is a DC, one is a Windows file server, and one is a Windows workstation. I intend to deploy a Ubuntu VM in the future.
The pre-existing machines are all domain-joined. I use the default switch for all three VMs, and there are no issues with comms.
Is there a way to route all internet traffic through my DC so my File Server and Workstation can access the internet? I intend to do it this way because I am doing all of this on my work laptop, setting up a lab instance for AD security applications testing (duh!).
I have tried the steps available on this site and many others involving external switch configuration, which has yielded no fruitful result. I wish to start from scratch. Can this be done? How can it be done?
DC-Windows Server 2022
File Server-Windows Server 2019
Workstation-Windows 10
Thank you in advance.

How does the DC itself get Internet access, at the moment?

As far as guessing game can go, since you must(should) have static IPs on all 3, I would place my bet on wrong network configuration on both VM's. Open "ncpa.cpl" from Run dialog on both machines and check configuration that they have proper DNS(ur DC prolly) and gateway(same as on DC).

@grawity_u1686
The DC gets internet access by using the default Hyper-V switch. I provide no details in ncpa.cpl and do the ipconfig /release & renew. Then enter the details from ipconfig. I use Google DNS as the second DNS address in ncpa.cpl. I provide the loopback address for the preferred DNS.

@Danijel
I will do that and let you know. Thank you for the input.

Okay, but in that case, why can't the other VMs access internet the same way?

@grawity_u1686
They can access the internet, but they cannot be part of my domain. It is either connect to domain or connect to the internet.
I wish to have a 'test' domain with my 3 Hyper-V VMs. So, connecting to the domain is paramount to me.

@Danijel
I tried installing the DHCP role in my DC to test if that would help but I am now getting a Online - Access is Denied error in my DCs server manager. It won't refresh. It won't let me add or remove features. Any ideas?

I'm guessing you assume this because they cannot resolve the domain via DNS? The usual workaround for that is to have the clients use the DC as their DNS server...but that has nothing to do with routing all traffic through it.

@grawity_u1686
Yes, I provide the DC's IP as the DNS for the other machines. But I want to route all traffic through my DC.

Right, you mentioned that, but the question remains: why do you want to do that? It is not well-supported and apparently has nothing to do with the reasons you've stated.

@grawity_u1686
I want to route all traffic because, in my testing, I will need all the machines to have Internet access. This is sorta throwing a wrench in it. If you don't mind, could you please shed some light on what you mean by it is not well-supported?

I mean that your machines already have internet access (through the Hyper-V host acting as a gateway), do they not? They can continue using the Hyper-V gateway at the same time as using the ADDC for DNS.

@grawity_u1686
Only the DC has Internet access. I am sorry if I have confused you. The server and the workstation do not have internet access. They can if I remove the DC's IP as the DNS. I wish to provide Internet access for the server and workstation while being connected to the Domain. Sadly, the machines stop communicating with each other once I remove the DC IP from DNS (obviously).

Then that still sounds like purely a DNS issue, not an "all traffic" issue (i.e. the workstation probably fails to resolve "outside" DNS names and and doesn't even get to the point of sending any other traffic in the first place) – specifying the DC as a DNS server definitely doesn't make the workstation route the 'other' traffic through the DC (instead that's what the gateway parameter does).

@sirshogunadvnse, you dont need DHCP for this to work at all. Two stations must have same gateway(whatever your router/wan exit is), for dns you can use your DC or simply use 1.1.1.1 for testing(or even gateway). The only FACTOR to let your all machines to internet is Gateway(it needs no approval unless you set some limits, but by default, there are none). If you know some web page ip, you dont need DNS either, but gateway will have access to internet(set all ips manually and in same subnet as router, set gateway and it should work, no dhcp or dns)IE. open this in browser;http://142.251.140.14
